# HttpClient with AllowAutoRedirect set to true is not working

Tags: c#, redirect, .net-core, httpclient, credentials

In .NET Core 3.1 web app I am trying to use **HttpClient** handler to redirect user to the website and to pass credentials along:

```
string url = "https://somewebsite.com/";

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"),
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var headerResponse = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

Debug.WriteLine("Response: " + headerResponse.StatusCode);

foreach (var item in headerResponse.Headers)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Header: {item.Key} - {string.Join(",", item.Value)}");
}
```

Documentation says that **client.GetAsync** call should be followed by redirect if **AllowAutoRedirect** is set to true. In my case I don't get redirected ever. I was reading that http site won't redirect to https and vice versa. I tried both http and https links, redirection just never happens. Here is an example that I was looking at: https://www.conradakunga.com/blog/http-redirects-using-httpclient/. I noticed that my response header is always missing "Location" item.

Here is the response that I get:

Response: OK
Header: Date - Fri, 22 Oct 2021 18:19:34 GMT
Header: Transfer-Encoding - chunked
Header: Connection - keep-alive
Header: Server - nginx
Header: Cache-Control - no-cache, private
Header: X-Frame-Options - SAMEORIGIN,SAMEORIGIN
Header: Set-Cookie - XSRF-TOKEN=blablablabla; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Header: X-XSS-Protection - 1; mode=block
Header: X-Content-Type-Options - nosniff

Any idea what is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You misunderstand the property, read docs remarks here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: To redirect a user you shoul not send the OK response but rather the 3xx response.
See here a selection of all statuscodes available. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @Nikosi. I did read that article again. I am not sure what I misunderstood. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Exitare.  Server is I am trying to redirect to is sending OK (200) response. How would I change response to 3xx? Thanks

Comment: I thnk there are some information missing, could you please add those? Either you have access to the servers code, in this case you just have to change the response of your API. 
if you do not have access to the servers code, because its a third party API, you have to manually redirect the user based on a successful request.

Comment: @Exitare. I should delete this post. I misunderstood this whole concept as Nkosi already stated. Thanks for your reply anyway.